# wp_handle_upload filter not called on wordpress built media upload from custom short code

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use wordpress built in media uploader using wp_enqueue_media(), and cpdmedia_upload.js adopted from https://derekspringer.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/using-the-wordpress-media-loader-in-the-front-end/

I am attempting to set the upload folder to different path. I could upload images, without any error. But files are getting saved in default location i.e. /wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/

With the help of error_log, I find none of the filters (wp_handle_upload_prefilter, wp_handle_upload) are called upon.

My code is as below.

```
//add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'cpd_general_pre_upload');
function cpd_general_pre_upload($file){
    error_log("cpd_general_pre_upload is called !\n", 3, trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR).'error.log');
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'cpd_general_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}

//add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'cpd_general_post_upload');
function cpd_general_post_upload($fileinfo){
    error_log("cpd_general_post_upload is called !\n", 3, trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR).'error.log');
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'cpd_general_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function cpd_general_upload_dir($path){     
    global $cpddir_year;
    error_log("cpd_general_upload_dir is called !\n", 3, trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR).'error.log');
    if(!empty($path['error'])) { return $path; } //error; do nothing.
    $path['path']    = trailingslashit($path['basedir']).'cpddata/general/'.$cpddir_year;
    $path['url']     = trailingslashit($path['baseurl']).'cpddata/general/'.$cpddir_year;
    $path['subdir']  = '/cpddata/general/'.$cpddir_year;
    file_put_contents('cmpicpd.log', 'cpd_general_upload_dir is completed !', FILE_APPEND);
    return $path;
}
```

My shortcode is below and called from a page.

```
add_shortcode('cpd_media_upload', 'cpd_media_upload_function');
function cpd_media_upload_function($atts, $content) {
    global $cpddir_year;
    $cpddir_year = date('Y');
    
    error_log("cpd_media_upload_function is called !\n", 3, trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR).'error.log');
    
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('cpdmedia_upload', plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) . 'js/cpdmedia_upload.js', array( 'jquery' ), filemtime(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/cpdmedia_upload.js'));
    
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'cpd_general_pre_upload');
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'cpd_general_post_upload');
    
    $str_html = "<form class='cpd-form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    $str_html .= "<div class='cpd-container'><div class='cpd-item'><div class='cpd-label'>Audited By</div><input type='text' name='cpd_audited_by' value='$cpd_audited_by' required /></div>";
    $str_html .= "<div class='cpd-item'><div class='cpd-label' myattr='cpd-lable'>Sign <small>(JPG,PNG; <=250KB)</small> <a myattr='nothing'></a></div><input type='file' name='cpd_audited_sign' class='upload-button' title='Select/Upload Media' btnselect='Select' value='$cpd_audited_sign' /></div></div>";   
    $str_html .= "</form>";
    return $str_html;
}
```